# Methods of alert dialog with Android API level 8

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

Can anyone tell me why if I declare an `AlertDialog` then the compiler will let me use methods like `setMessage()` or `setTitle()`?

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

The target is API level 15 and minimun is 8, so the code should work with API 8.

Thank you very much!

Comment: non-Android programmer here, but is a `Dialog` different than an `AlertDialog`?

Comment: Sorry! I have the same problem with AlertDialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `setMessage()` is not a method of the class `Dialog`, regardless the API level. This is a method of `AlertDialog`.
- `Dialog(Context)` and `setTitle()` work under Android 8.

More generally, I am using the following code with API 8 with no problem. This is an `AlertDialog`-based piece of code but it sounds in accordance with your use case as you were speaking about `setMessage()`.

```
    AlertDialog dlg = null;

    if (!activity.isFinishing()) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        builder.setTitle(resTitle)
               .setMessage(text)
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton(resOk, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       if (notify != null) { // 'notify' is a Handler
                           notify.sendEmptyMessage(MODAL_ALERT_SEEN);
                       }
                       dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               }
        );

        dlg = builder.create();
        dlg.show();
    }
```

For further details, you can check the official [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html). There's an API level selector that grays out the methods not applicable to the API level you wish to be compatible with:

[image: Compatibility level on the API documentation]

Comment: very good solution! thank's you very much.
Do you know where i can get information about customize AlertDialog?

Comment: StackOverflow is full of information about that. And the link pointed by @Gintas_ in his answer is a really good point to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Because Dialog doesn't have these methods, these are AlertDialog methods. Use [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) instead. Usage example can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. android:minSdkVersion="8"
2. android:targetSdkVersion="15"

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alert Builder");
   alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("AlertDialog in API level 8");
   AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
   alertDialog.show();
   ```

   It works for me Happy Coding.